# C++ runtime error invalid vptr when compiling with gcc 8.1 and gcc 8.2

Tags: c++, gcc, vtable, vptr, gcc8

I have a strange runtime error that only happens with GCC 8.2 and GCC 8.1.

When attempting to delete a class with multiple inheritances, the compiler raises a runtime error related to a corrupted virtual pointer.

This minimal example can be found in the godbolt.

https://godbolt.org/z/GYfWYdeqW

In the code snippet, it is possible to confirm that any combination in which flags `fsanitize=undefined` and `-fno-sanitize-recover=undefined` aren't present together enables the code to run successfully.

**Question**

What can be done in the code to enable execution with GCC 8.1 or 8.2 while using `-fsanitize=undefined` and C++14?

**Acceptable answers:**

- Show that it is impossible to execute the code under the conditions specified.
- Suggest a modification that enables the code to execute.

---

### Anexes

**MINIMAL CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {std::cout << "Deleting Base!\n";}
};

class DerivedLeft : public virtual Base
{
public:
    virtual ~DerivedLeft() override {std::cout << "Deleting DerivedLeft!\n";}
};


class DerivedRight : public virtual Base
{
public:
    virtual ~DerivedRight() override {std::cout << "Deleting DerivedRight!\n";}
    virtual void Release() noexcept = 0;
};

class CustomDeleter final
{
public:
  void operator()(DerivedRight const* ptr) const noexcept {
    DerivedRight* const non_const_ptr{const_cast<DerivedRight*>(ptr)};
    if (non_const_ptr != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "CustomDeleter working!\n";
        non_const_ptr->Release();
    }
  }
};

class Mock : 
    public DerivedLeft, 
    public DerivedRight
{
public:
    Mock() {std::cout << "Creating Mock!\n";}
    virtual ~Mock() override {std::cout << "Deleting Mock!\n";}
    void Release() noexcept override { delete this; };

    using Uptr = std::unique_ptr<Mock, CustomDeleter>;
    static Uptr Create() { return Uptr(new Mock()); }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    auto Mock = Mock::Create();
    std::cout << "Scope End!\n";
}
```

**ERROR**

```
/app/example.cpp:43:30: runtime error: member call on address 0x602000000010 which does not point to an object of type 'Base'
0x602000000010: note: object has invalid vptr
 01 00 80 55  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              invalid vptr
```

**Compiler flags**

```
-fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=undefined
```

Comment: Not all sanitizers play well together. Perhaps you're trying to do too much simultaneously?

Comment: Also, `delete this`? That's something you have to be ***very*** careful about. Once you have done that no member variables might be accessed, and that includes the hidden virtual table!

Comment: And why do your deleter take a pointer to a *constant* object? There's no such requirement. In most cases using `const_cast` should be avoided, and almost seen as an error.

Comment: AddressSanitizer seems unrelated to the issue, so you might as well take it out to avoid confusion.  The other thing that's odd is that if you keep `-fsanitize=undefined` but remove `-fno-sanitize-recover=undefined` then it runs to completion.  I thought that even without recovery, it was still supposed to report an error at the end.

Comment: Assuming that your code is in fact legal (which I haven't checked), it could simply be a bug in that version of gcc.  So would "upgrade your compiler" be an acceptable answer?  Or, identify the patch that fixed the bug (e.g. with a big `git bisect` on gcc) and backport it yourself.

Comment: Removing `delete this;` fixes that error.  The sanitizer must be assuming that `this` points to a valid class.

Comment: It doesn't report anything in gcc 8.3 and above either

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, the original code has some references to documentation related to this `const_cast`. I need to find them and take a look before telling you if it is necessary.

Comment: Most of this code is red herring. A straight diamond inheritance with no bells and whistles gives [the same error](https://godbolt.org/z/61WETfso4). This is probably a sanitizer bug, because removing `-fno-sanitize-recover=undefined` makes the error disappear, which should not happen.

Comment: The right way to enable execution is probably ditching `-fno-sanitize-recover=undefined`, or perhaps UBSan itself, because this particular version seems buggy.